# how to retrieve files when editing a file manager in moodle

Tags: php, android-activity, module, moodle

I am currently doing an internship and I tried to make an activity module to show playlist, from video given by a filemanager. I succeed to send the video to the database but when I want to edit my module, it doesn't show any videos in the filemanager.

I read the moodle documentation about [file API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#File_browsing_support) and I decided to use the following code (Load existing files into draft area)

:

```
 if (empty($entry->id)) {
$entry = new stdClass;
$entry->id = null;
}

$draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('attachments');
file_prepare_draft_area($draftitemid, $context->id, 'mod_glossary','attachment', $entry->id,array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'maxfiles' => 50));
$entry->attachments = $draftitemid;
$mform->set_data($entry);
```

So I put the following lines in my mod_form.php :

```
  $filemanager_options = array();
    $filemanager_options['accepted_types'] = '*';
    $filemanager_options['maxbytes'] = 0;
    $filemanager_options['maxfiles'] = -1;
    $filemanager_options['mainfile'] = true;

        $mform->addElement('filemanager', 'files', get_string('selectfiles'), null, $filemanager_options);



if (empty($entry->id)) {
    $entry = new stdClass;
    $entry->id = null;
}

$draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('mymanager');


file_prepare_draft_area($draftitemid, $this->context->id, 'mod_playlist', 'content', 0,
                      array('subdirs'=>true));

$entry->attachments = $draftitemid;

$mform->set_data($entry);
```

The problem is that the file manager is still empty, and the line  "$mform->set_data($entry); " makes the page to crash(blank).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a template for uploading files.

In local/myplugin/upload.php

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/upload_form.php');

require_login();

$context = context_system::instance();

require_capability('local/myplugin:upload', $context);

$pageurl = new moodle_url('/local/myplugin/upload.php');
$heading = get_string('myupload', 'local_myplugin');
$PAGE->set_context($context);
$PAGE->set_heading(format_string($heading));
$PAGE->set_title(format_string($heading));
$PAGE->set_url('/local/myplugin/upload.php');

echo $OUTPUT->header();
echo $OUTPUT->heading($heading);

$fileoptions = array(
        'maxbytes' => 0,
        'maxfiles' => '1',
        'subdirs' => 0,
        'context' => context_system::instance()
);

$data = new stdClass();

$data = file_prepare_standard_filemanager($data, 'myfiles',
        $fileoptions, context_system::instance(), 'local_myplugin', 'myfiles', 0); // 0 is the item id.

$mform = new upload_form(
    null,
    array(
        'fileoptions' => $fileoptions,
    )
);

if ($formdata = $mform->get_data()) {
    // Save the file.
    $data = file_postupdate_standard_filemanager($data, 'myfiles',
            $fileoptions, context_system::instance(), 'local_myplugin', 'myfiles', 0);
} else {
    // Display the form.
    $mform->set_data($data);
    $mform->display();
}

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Then in local/myplugin/upload_form.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

require_once($CFG->libdir . '/formslib.php');

class upload_form extends moodleform {

    public function definition() {
        $mform =& $this->_form;

        $fileoptions = $this->_customdata['fileoptions'];

        $mform->addElement('filemanager', 'myfiles_filemanager',
                get_string('myfiles', 'local_myplugin'), null, $fileoptions);

        $this->add_action_buttons(false, get_string('save', 'local_myplugin'));

    }
}
```

You will also need this in /local/myplugin/lib.php

```
function local_myplugin_pluginfile($course, $cm, $context, $filearea, $args, $forcedownload, array $options = array()) {

    if ($context->contextlevel != CONTEXT_SYSTEM) {
        send_file_not_found();
    }

    $fs = get_file_storage();
    $file = $fs->get_file($context->id, 'local_myplugin', $filearea, $args[0], '/', $args[1]);

    send_stored_file($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I needed to know ! :)

Comment: Dude... that lib.php saved me another day of work. I've already spend one day working lib.php on the file display part. The original from the documentation simply doesn't work for me. Thank you!